# Product on Tensor Products

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, tensor-calculus

I'm trying to understand how products on tensor products work. For instance, in quantum mechanics, you have ($x$ tensor $y$) times ($z$ tensor $a$), where $x$, $y$, $z$, $a$ are all operators acting on a Hilbert space. I want to believe that it's just $xz$ tensor $ya$, but I'm looking online and that only applies for von Neumann algebras (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra), but I'm not sure if the operators in quantum mechanics forms a ring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are a mathematician that just wants to prove results you can try to make up definition of products of "operators" and try to make a $W^*$ or a $C^*$ algebra out of them (and make them a ring or not or whatever you want).  But you are being concrete and saying that these are operators on a Hilbert Space, so you can answer your own question by looking at how the operators act on the Hilbert Space.

For instance if you take a tensor product of Hilbert Spaces, with elements $v\otimes w$ and your operator $V\otimes W$ is defined by $(V\otimes W)(v\otimes w)= (Vv)\otimes (Ww)$, then since you've said how your operators act, then we can deduce that:

$$(V_2\otimes W_2)\circ (V_1\otimes W_1)=(V_2\circ V_1)\otimes (W_2\circ W_1).$$

Since both obviously send $v\otimes w$ to $V_2(V_1(v)) \otimes W_2(W_1(w))$.

Comment: The kind of answer a good educator gives. I especially like answers that appeal to the questioner's own ability to engender confidence to grapple with ideas they might be struggling with. Fantasic!

Comment: Thanks!!
Can't believe I didn't think about its action an element. Thanks again!!